# When to override get method in Django CBV?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I've been learning Django and one source of confusion I have is with class based views and when to override the get method. I've looked through the documentation and it explains what get does but it doesn't explain when I should override get.

I originally created a view this way:

```
class ExampleView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'ppm/ppm.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get(self, request):
        profiles_set = EmployeeProfile.objects.all()
        context = {
            'profiles_set': profiles_set,
            'title': 'Employee Profiles'
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

But I was recently told that my code was simple of enough for the default implementation, and that all I needed was this:

```
class ExampleView(generic.ListView):
    model = EmployeeProfile
    template_name = 'ppm/ppm.html'
```

So my Question is this: In what scenario/circumstance should I override the get method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the builtin generic views, then you should rarely have to override `get()`. You'll end up either duplicating lots of functionality, or break features of the view.

For example, the [`paginate_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginate_by) option will no longer work in your view, because you are not slicing the queryset in your `get()` method.

If you are using a generic class based view like `ListView`, you should try to override specific attributes or methods where possible, rather than overriding `get()`.

The advantage of your view which overrides `get()` is that it's very clear what it does. You can see that the view fetches a queryset, includes it in a context, then renders the templates. You don't need to know about `ListView` to understand the view.

If you like the explicitness of overriding `get()` subclass [`View`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#view) instead. You aren't using any of the features of `ListView`, so it doesn't make sense to subclass it.

```
from django.views.generic import View

class ExampleView(View):
    template_name = 'ppm/ppm.html'

    def get(self, request):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `get` method when you specifically want to do something other than the default view does. In this case, your code isn't doing anything other than rendering the template with the list of all `EmployeeProfile` objects, which is exactly what the generic `ListView` would do.

You might override it if you want to do something more complicated. For example, maybe you want to filter based on a URL parameter:

```
class ExampleView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'ppm/ppm.html'

    def get(self, request):
        manager = request.GET.get('manager', None)
        if manager:
            profiles_set = EmployeeProfile.objects.filter(manager=manager)
        else:
            profiles_set = EmployeeProfile.objects.all()
        context = {
            'profiles_set': profiles_set,
            'title': 'Employee Profiles'
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: Note that this example still doesn't require you to override `get()` - it would be better to override [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) instead.