# Django docs -- CBVs: Why not just define a get() method that takes an argument from a URL?

Tags: python, django

Noob here going through the Django docs, trying to get a grip on how it all fits together.

In [this section of their document on generic class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects), they demonstrate the hard-coding of filter parameters for a particular publisher (in this example) into `ListView`'s `queryset` attribute and suggest that doing so will become problematic once you need separate `ListView`s for every publisher. That makes sense to me. In the [next section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) they suggest overriding `ListView`'s `get_queryset()` method this way:

```
class PublisherBookList(ListView):

template_name = 'books/books_by_publisher.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    self.publisher = get_object_or_404(Publisher, 
    name=self.kwargs['publisher'])
    return Book.objects.filter(publisher=self.publisher)
```

My question is, why not just declare a `get()` method in `ListView` and allow `get()` to take in `publisher` from the URL? What am I missing here?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36922405/641249

Comment: give a try to that library `django-filter` and have a look on that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24306533/953553